# Transform a plain HTML script to jsx

Tags: html, reactjs, jsx

I'm struggling with a quite simple issue here and I need some help. My HTML script is this

```
<nav class="mainNav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="active">δσαδσαδσαδσα</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">δσαδσαδσαδσα</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

I want to write it using the Link tag from react-router so I'm writing

```
<ul className="main-nav">
  <NavLink to="/" onlyActiveOnIndex>δσαδσαδ</NavLink>
  <NavLink to="/" onlyActiveOnIndex>δσαδσαδ</NavLink>
</ul>
```

where NavLink is a simple widget with this code:

```
export default function (props) {
  return (
    <Link
      {...props}
    />);
}
```

What am I missing? My layout is not the same as the HTML script

Comment: I did not understand the problem. Can you clarify your issue and point to where it's not working?

Comment: My issue is that my plain html script has not the same layout as my code with the Navlink component and i cannot understand why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean replacing your `<a />` links with `<NavLink />` ?

```
<nav className="mainNav">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <NavLink to="/" onlyActiveOnIndex>δσαδσαδ</NavLink>
    </li>
    <li>
      <NavLink to="/" onlyActiveOnIndex>δσαδσαδ</NavLink>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Exactly i was getting confused

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to place your `NavLink` component inside the `li` tags.

```
<nav class="mainNav">
  <ul>
    <li><NavLink to="/" onlyActiveOnIndex>δσαδσαδ</NavLink></li>
    <li><NavLink to="/" onlyActiveOnIndex>δσαδσαδ</NavLink></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```